# Mock Static Void methods using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, static-methods, void

I have a class as follows:

```
class Abc{
    static void fun() throws AbcException{
        throw new Exception("Some exception message");
    }
    
    static{
        try{
            fun();
        }catch(AbcException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

fun() calls some other function and there is a chain of functions following it which throws AbcException if the environment is not configured properly. In Unit Test environment, I faced the AbcException as explained below.

(Also, there are many other methods in this class which I have mentioned)

I want to create an instance of class Abc in my test file. I'm using JUnit 4 and Mockito 4.8.1. I tried the following :

1. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2027
2. https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2390

I wrote my test as follows:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    try (MockedStatic<Abc> abc = mockStatic(Abc.class)) {
        // some test setup
    }
}
```

This didn't help because the AbcException was thrown when mockStatic(Abc.class) was called.

Is there a way to mock Abc class successfully in this case?

Comment: Tough one - a static initializer block is executed very early, not sure mockito can mock before loading the class... see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130461/when-is-the-static-block-of-a-class-executed

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use heavier tools for this one - e.g. PowerMock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking Static Blocks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61150/mocking-static-blocks-in-java)

Comment: I'm thinking of PowerMock as the second option. Wanted to know if something is possible with mockito first

Comment: What test cases you are going to write?

Comment: I solved this without mocking. I initialised my Unit test environment properly with the application context.

Answer (score 0):

For Void methods with Mockito you can :

[Simple Mocking and verifying](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)

[Argument Capture](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15)

[Answering a Call to Void](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#37)

[Partial Mocking](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12)